# MasterFormat Classification Regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel, pcre

I need a recipe for validating a MasterFormat classification string that consists of a set of numbers followed by a title string.

The numbers that begin the string must be:

3 sets of 2 digits separated by spaces:

`09 68 13`

The last set of digits can also be a decimal:

`09 68 13.36`

Followed by a space

Then a string of words to represent the title, the first letter of each word to caps

`09 68 13 Tile Carpeting`

`09 68 13.36 Tile Carpeting`

I have a start which seems to work but I can't seem to get the word string added in correctly.

```
\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}(\.\d{2}){0,1}
```

This will be validated in a Laravel Rule.

Comment: Show what you tried to match the word string. What are the requirements for the title?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is the full piece I have now that doesn't quite work: `/\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}(\.\d{2}){0,1}(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)+\s+/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the title is always one or multiple words, separated by spaces. that's all

Comment: `/^\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}(?:\.\d{2})?(?:[A-Za-z]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)*)?\s*$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no this doesn't seem to get it. I entered `09 68 13 Tile Carpeting` which is valid and it returned as a mismatch.

Comment: Missed a whitespace, `/^\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}(?:\.\d{2})?(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)*)?\s*$/`, see https://regex101.com/r/4s2GJj/1

Comment: Getting closer ... numbers work, but it's still allowing words to be entered in lowercase instead of capitalized. `09 68 13 tile carpeting` validates and it shouldn't. And it can be entered with no title at all and it validates. No bueno.

Comment: [Better](https://regex101.com/r/4s2GJj/2)?

Comment: Ok title casing works ... but it can still be entered without a title. Both the numbers and the title are required.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/4s2GJj/3 ?

Comment: BINGO! @WiktorStribiżew you are the man! Thanks so much. Works great. Can you post as the answer and I'll select. I appreciate your help so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}(?:\.\d{2})?\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*)*\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4s2GJj/3). **Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}` - two digits, whitespace, two digits, whitespace, two digits
- `(?:\.\d{2})?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of a `.` and then two digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\p{Lu}\p{L}*` -  an uppercase letter followed with 0+ letters
- `(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of 1+ whitespaces followed with an uppercase letter followed with 0+ letters
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.